# Where are the dialogs in JavaFX 8 Update 60

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, dialog

at this site: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/ it is explained, that the official JavaFX dialogs will be implemented in JavaFX 8 Update 40. I am using JavaFX 8 Update 60 (JDK), but I don't have any class called `Alert` or something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have the right version ?

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaFX 8u40, there is indeed an [`Alert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) class. The import is:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry guys. I've found the solution. In my eclipse installation  it switched from JDK x32 to JDK x64 which contains just JavaFX 8 Update 5. I added the right JDK to Eclipse and now it is working.

Comment: I would delete the question, I don't think it can help anybody